# Unable to retrieve facebook live comments in real-time

Tags: http, go, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve facebook live comments in real time. I have read this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments)
This is my implementation:

```
func getLiveComments(liveId, token string) {
    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/%s/live_comments?access_token=%s&comment_rate=one_per_two_seconds&fields=from{name,id},message",
        liveId, url.QueryEscape(token))
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Get: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(resp.Body)
    for {
        // got stuck here
        line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        log.Println(string(line))
    }
}
```

But it got stuck at `line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')`.
I can use the `liveId` and `token` to get comments from [facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%7Blive-video-id%7D%2Fcomments&version=v3.2)

Comment: loose the NewReader and the for loop and try ``body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)``  ``log.Printf("%v", body)`` . Maybe there are no newlines in the json output from the graph